# initwithint warning, no method found?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, integer, warnings, init

I have a warning and just can't work out how to make it go away.

In my .h I have this...

```
-(void)restartTimer;
```

Then the in my .m I have...

```
-(void)restartTimer{
TimerViewController *TimerView = [[TimerViewController alloc]
  initWithInt:hStart
  number:mStart];
```

I get this error:

Warning: no '-initWithInt:number.' method found.

I am sure it is very straightforward, the code still works. If anyone can suggest any ways to solve it that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Not to be rude or anything, but please try to note what language you're using in the tags, title, or body of your question. Its easy enough to see here that this is an objective-c question but it may not be next time. Again not trying to be rude just offering some helpful advice! :)

Comment: sure I'm a little new to this :-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)restartTimer{
    TimerViewController *TimerView = [[TimerViewController alloc]
        initWithInt:hStart
             number:mStart];
...
}
```

(1) `TimerView` should be `timerView`, as per Objective-C naming conventions

(2) Your TimerViewController.h should have a declaration something like:

```
- (TimerViewController *) initWithInt: (NSInteger) hStart number: (NSInteger) mStart;
```

(assuming that you want hStart and mStart to be integers).

(3) You must import TimerViewController.h in the implementation file that the above code appears in, either directly or indirectly (because it is imported by something else, potentially the project's PCH file).

(4) A better name for the method might be:

```
- (TimerViewController *) initWithHStart: (NSInteger) hStart mStart: (NSInteger) mStart;
```

Or something similar -- that is, the method should describe the nature of the arguments that it takes.

Answer (score 1):

This means the compiler can't find such a method at compile time. Just include the header of `TimerViewController` in your `.m` file.

Comment: By doing #import "TimerViewController.h" ? I already have that

Comment: are you sure this exact method exists in your implementation of TimerViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Import the header file my .h will resolve this problem

Answer (score -1):

The code still works because Objective-C allows sending messages to `nil` objects thus `*TimerView` is `nil`.

Comment: TimerView isn't actually involved at the point in time the method is invoked.